# Laravel Eloquent belongsToMany() with string pk converted to 0

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Trying to work through an issue with belongsToMany() where my pk is a string (similar to uuid)

simple products <-- product_productgroups --> productgroups

but products primary key on products is apk varchar(50)

when I use integer values, everything is fine, but if I use strings, they are converted to 0 when searching the pivot table:

```
$product = App\Products::with('productgroups')->find('B00AE38KM');

"select * from `products` where `products`.`apk` = ? limit 1"
```

array:1 [▼
  0 => "B00AE38KM"
]

"select `productgroups`.*, `product_productgroup`.`product_apk` as `pivot_product_apk`, `product_productgroup`.`productgroup_id` as `pivot_productgroup_id` from `productgroups` inner join `product_productgroup` on `productgroups`.`id` = `product_productgroup`.`productgroup_id` where `product_productgroup`.`product_apk` in (?)"

array:1 [▼
  0 => 0
]

My Products model has:

```
    public function productgroups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ProductGroups', 
           'product_productgroup', 
           'product_apk', 
           'productgroup_id');
    }
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Solved - nothing to do with the relationships, but rather on the model.

look at Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model & trace through the getAttribute() function to where it calls getCasts().

You'll see that if the model $incrementing is true & this field is the primaryKey, it is cast to int;

Solution:

at the top of your model,

```
    protected $incrementing = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set model's

```php
protected $keyType = 'string';
```